Laravel images showing on public server but not 127.0.0.1:8000
my question may not be fully understood from the title, I apologize for that.
The images uploaded in my cPanel are not loaded at the address where I run the php artisan serve command, I get a 404.
I tried php artisan storage:link but it didn't work. I played around with filesystem.php and it didn't work again. I didn't see any problems with my file permissions either. Am I not doing something I don't know about?
I would be happy if you help
here codes:
<?php

return [

    'default' => 'local',


    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => storage_path('app'),
            'throw'  => false,
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver'     => 'local',
            'root'       => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url'        => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw'      => false,
        ], 

        'custom' => [
            'driver'     => 'local',
            'root'       => public_path('storage'),
            'url'        => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw'      => false,
        ],

        'chat' => [
            'driver'     => 'local',
            'root'       => public_path('storage/chat'),
            'url'        => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/storage/chat',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw'      => false,
        ],
        
                    'wasabi' => [
                'driver' => 'wasabi',
                'key' => env('WASABI_KEY'),
                'secret' => env('WASABI_SECRET'),
                'region' => env('WASABI_REGION'),
                'bucket' => env('WASABI_BUCKET'),
            ],

        's3' => [
            'driver'                  => 's3',
            'key'                     => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret'                  => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region'                  => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket'                  => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url'                     => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint'                => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw'                   => false,
        ]

    ],

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

];


app.php
   /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url'       => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',

    'asset_url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/public',


.env
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000/

php artisan storage:link
ERROR  The [C:\Users\..\..\project\public\storage] link already exists. 

It seems the storage is already linked. I am not sure what folder do you have inside public folder, for example,
If the folder structure is like public/storage/abc.png then the link will be something like this,
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/abc.png

check this resolves your issue, or please elaborate what you are trying and what you are getting.
Thanks

thanks for help, on server /public/storage/img/abc.png openning but not on the local server. i deleted /public and its fixed

You need to run below command
php artisan storage:link

after that you can directly access the image or files
Example: http://127.0.0.1:8000/abc.png


ref: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/filesystem
